# How do I determine how future-proof and stable a router is?

Tags: wireless-router

I mentioned in my [last question](https://superuser.com/questions/403692/how-can-i-fix-my-wrt54gls-constant-crashing) that my wireless router had a bad habit of crashing. After consulting with the Super User chatroom, as well as my sysadmin, I've decided I need a new router. However, **I'm unsure how to evaluate all these tech specs that get touted about**.

The two things that seem to be the most important to me are:

1. keeping my router future-proof (as standards evolve and change), and
2. ensuring its stability.

Unfortunately, **I'm not sure what, exactly, I should be looking for in the tech specs or the item description that can give me a good idea of how stable or future-proof my router will be**.

What should I look for? Can I determine stability without having to try the device out myself?

Please note: I'm *not* a battle-hardened power user by any means, so I'll likely be reliant on the given firmware for my router. My last router lasted me like four years, so I mostly just want something that'll cover a 500 sqft apartment in New York with minimal crashing, so that I can watch Hulu in peace. And make Skype calls.

Comment: No such thing as future proof when it comes to computer related electronics.

Comment: Welcome to SU.  Shopping and buying recommendations are off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: 3rd-party firmware, such as dd-wrt and tomato, often include many more features than the stock firmware includes. You might want to look into a wireless router that is listed on the websites of 3rd-party firmware if you choose to go that route.

Comment: @techie007 - this is not a shopping recommendation.

Comment: Hopefully my edit clarifies that she's looking for the specific tech specs for routers that suggest they are stable and future proof.

Comment: @ChrisF it _was_ a buying recommendation, with linked products and all.  It's better now, but still a loaded question that will probably only solicit opinion and personal experiences, as I doubt anyone can nail down how to pick a "stable" and "future-proof" electronic device based on specs.  History shows that even the best brands, with the best models still have occasional manufacturing defects and firmware problems, often which don't seem to show up until it's been EOL'd and no-longer supported. :/  Pick a brand you like, and a model with the features you require and with a long warranty. :)

Comment: @techie007 that's as good an answer as I wanted. :D